# java compiler not give all error at a time

Tags: java

```
        System.out.println("First eror ::  without semicolon ") // first Error
        System.Out.println("This second error :: OUT object not used proper :: "); //second error


class TestCompilation
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {   
        System.out.println("Hello no semicolon::")//First Error 
        System.Out.println("Hello out spell not correctely::"); //Second Error 

        }

}
```

whenever i compile above code by JAVAC command in cmd it gives only First Error means not give second Error. In java language partially compiler and partially interpreter and In java first compilation happen so compiler should list out all errors but it gives me only single error. why its happening ? i dont understand so please help me out from this problem..

---

I think now i am clear about my question means compiler works totally ...

For that i create simple example it will help you to understand the java compiler working .

```
class TestCompilation
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {   
        Syste.out.rintln("Hello");//First Error 
        Syste.Out.rintln("Hello");//Second Error (Not printed at compiler time because it syntatically correct as in compiler first phase)  
        Hitesh542.add(); //there is no such class called Hitesh542.- but compiler thinks that it is right way to call the method. So it passes the first time.
        Hitesh542.add()();//Look out here.. There is a problem, that we can't call a method like this..So it will show the error on first lookup.
        System.otu.println("Hello")//second  Errorasdasdas

        if(); //look this is also an error.- A BASIC syntax error shown at the first lookup.

        try{
            int i = 10 / 0;
        }
        //Third error

        //So bottom line is the JAVA syntatical errors are checked first i.e The SYNTAX of JAVA not the classes or objects.
        //But obv is the first thing is Java Compiler should get the Java class first for compilation on proper path. :)
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried ? Post your codes.

Comment: @JDeveloper: I think his question is clear.

Comment: @JDeveloper :"Post your codes"??? Read the Question Properly

Comment: @improver you are right I misunderstood this question .

Comment: class TestCompilation
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 { 
  Syste.out.rintln("Hello");//First Error 
  Syste.Out.rintln("Hello");//Second Error (Not printed at compiler)                                          }        }

Comment: @JDeveloper :: i POsted my code it just two lines of code ...when i compile above program , compiler give me only first error then what about second error ... (as per compiler work :: listed all error.)

Comment: @Hitesh542 thanks for your effort.I got your doubts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd say this has to do with how compilers often work:

1. **Lexical analysis** is performed, where the source code is converted into a sequence of "tokens".
2. The code is **parsed**, where the compiler checks whether the tokens meet the language syntax. This is where your first line would fail: every statement in Java must be ended with a semicolon.
3. **Semantic analysis** is performed, where the compiler tries to resolve variables, methods, etc. according to the list of known symbols - in Java, this would roughly translate to your classpath.
4. **Code is generated** where the source statements are translated either into native bytecode or some intermediate bytecode (the latter is the case for Java).

If one of the steps fails, the process must stop, because a compiler cannot perform semantic analysis when the code doesn't meet the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> In java language partially compiler and partially interpreter and In java first compilation happen so compiler should list out all errors

I'm sorry to disappoint you but that's a *non sequitur.* The interpreter isn't present at compile time and has nothing whatsoever to do with it.

The compiler can't determine all your errors at once, if for example some of them are syntax errors which preclude semantic analysis, or a simple semantic error precludes further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Your second error is an error only in a **Java program**, i.e. a string that conforms to the Java syntax. The notion of a non syntactic error in a non-program does not make sense. For the compiler, all strings that are not syntactically correct have the same meaning: none.

It is like you submit the following "program":

```
double x = 5.3; x[42] = 0;
```

and complain that the compiler does not tell you that a double value cannot be indexed.

For example, giving this input in a java source file in eclipse gives only "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens."

Comment: Unfortunately for your answer, the compiler *does* tell you more or less exactly that: 'error: array required, but double found'. The string you have posterd *is* part of a legal Java program, and so doesn't illustrate your point in the slightest.

Comment: @EJP I mean the above to be the whole program text. Since there is no class, the compiler need not bother if the text would be a valid part of a java program.